# Change background color of Google AdMob Native Ad Swift

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I Have implemented `Google AdMob's Native Ads` primarily because it's easy to customize but I can't seem to find out **how to change the background color of the ad itself**, I've looked everywhere and tried it all but haven't found an answer yet.

#### This is the code I'm using to style the Ad

```
func adLoader(_ adLoader: GADAdLoader, didReceive nativeAd: GADUnifiedNativeAd) {
    templateView?.nativeAd = nativeAd
    let styles : [GADTNativeTemplateStyleKey: NSObject] = [
        .mainBackgroundColor: UIColor.red,
        .primaryFontColor: UIColor(named: "Primary Text")!,
        .secondaryFontColor: UIColor(named: "Secondary Text")!,
        .tertiaryFontColor: UIColor(named: "Secondary Text")!,
        .primaryFont: UIFont.rounded(ofSize: 17, weight: .semibold),
        .secondaryFont: UIFont.rounded(ofSize: 15, weight: .medium),
        .tertiaryFont: UIFont.rounded(ofSize: 15, weight: .medium),
        .callToActionBackgroundColor: UIColor(.accentColor),
        .cornerRadius: NSNumber(floatLiteral: 10.0)
    ]
    templateView?.styles = styles
    templateView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
}
```

#### And this is a screenshot of the ad in the simulator

I switched to dark mode because my goal is to conform the background of the ad to the background of the view.

[image]

Comment: Isn't the ad just an image coming from the network? I mean if the ad is about shoes and it shows a picture of someone wearing shoes for the whole width of the ad you shouldn't be able to change it.

Comment: No it isn't, this particular ad I screenshoted doesn't have an image but other ones do in a small rectangle, not in the background.

Answer (score 1):

I Had to change the view directly by going in the template files and changing the background color to clear
[image]